# How to retain attached file when cancel browse another file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem to retain attached files in file input `<input type="file">` after cancelled choose file again. Anyone have idea to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? You want that the cancel button doesn't reset your input field?

Comment: Yap. First I select a file, then I browse again but not select file. I want the input file to keep the first file I selected.

Comment: What do you mean by "browse again"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the built-in behaviour of the browser when dealing with the `<file>` element. If you select a document, then click "Browse" again, but then click "Cancel" it clears the field.

Nothing you can do about it, other than maybe using a plugin for uploading files, (such as https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ for example) which allows the user to upload files using a different UI.